# How to add comma and horizontal gridline to y-axis tick marks in base R

Tags: r

I am looking to add commas to the numbers on my y-axis tick marks (i.e. "260,000") and horizontal gridlines. Any idea how to do this in base R? Edit: ignore the mumbo jumbo that appears after the properly formatted code on my question.For some reason I'm unable to delete it.

```
# Create the data for the chart.
breast <- c(264000,275000,280000,289000,294000)
prostate <- c(148000,201000,235000, 275000,320000) 
year <- c("2019","2020","2021","2022", "2023")

# Calculate range from 0 to max value of cars and trucks

# Graph autos using y axis that ranges from 0 to max 
# value in cars or trucks vector.  Turn off axes and 
# annotations (axis labels) so we can specify them ourself
plot(breast, type="o", col="pink2", ylim=c(0,350000),pch=22,lty=2,
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, lwd=3)
lines(prostate, type = "o", pch=22, lty=2, col = "steelblue2", 
      lwd=3)

# Make x axis using year labels
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("2019","2020","2021","2022","2023"))

# Make y axis with horizontal labels that display ticks at 
# every 4 marks. 4*0:g_range[2] is equivalent to c(0,4,8,12).
axis(2, las=1)

# Create box around plot
#box() REMOVE COMMENT HASHTAG IF YOU WANT TO PUT A BOX 
#AROUND PLOT

# Label the x and y axes with dark green text
#title(xlab="Year") UNCOMMENT FOR Y AXIS LABEL
legend(3.2,90000, legend=c('Breast Cancer', 
                           'Prostate Cancer'), 
       col=c('steelblue1', 'pink2'), 
       lty=2, bty='n', lwd=3)
```

Comment: Would you like your numbers to be in the following format for example? `264,000`

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `labels` argument in `axis`, with the values set by `prettyNum`:

```r
breast   <- c(264000, 275000, 280000, 289000, 294000)
prostate <- c(148000, 201000, 235000, 275000, 320000) 
year     <- c("2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023")

plot(x = year, ylim = c(0, 350000), axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE, type = "n")
abline(h = seq(0, 350000, 50000), col = "gray90", lwd = 1)
lines(breast, type = "o", pch = 22, lty = 2, lwd = 3, col = "pink2")
lines(prostate, type = "o", pch = 22, lty = 2, lwd = 3, col = "steelblue2")
axis(1, at = 1:5, lab = 2019:2023)
axis(2, at = seq(0, 350000, 50000), las = 1, 
     labels = prettyNum(seq(0, 350000, 50000), 
                        big.mark = ',', 
                        scientific = FALSE))
legend(3.2,90000, legend = c('Breast Cancer', 'Prostate Cancer'), 
       col = c('steelblue1', 'pink2'), lty = 2, bty = 'n', lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to add horizontal gridlines at the y tick marks?